# MySQL trigger - increasing count depending of the inserted value

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER instant_messages_a BEFORE INSERT ON messages_messages
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.received = 1 THEN

INSERT INTO messages_folders (id, addressee, sender, count_total, updated_time, nickname, subject, ipadr, new_messages, photo) VALUES
(NULL,NEW.addressee_id,NEW.sender_id,1,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),NEW.nickname,NEW.subject,NEW.ipadr,1,0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count_total=count_total+1,updated_time=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),subject=NEW.subject,ipadr=NEW.ipadr,new_messages=new_messages+1,photo=NEW.photo;

ELSE

INSERT INTO messages_folders (id, addressee, sender, count_total, updated_time, nickname, subject, ipadr, new_messages, photo) VALUES
(NULL,NEW.addressee_id,NEW.sender_id,1,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),NEW.nickname,NEW.subject,0,0,0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count_total=count_total+1;

END IF;

END
```

**Question N 1**

MySQL query inserts `$_POST['received']` value into `instant_messages_a`. This value is always 0 or 1. I would like to increase the values of `count_total` and `new_messages` columns in `messages_folders` table depending of the `$_POST['received']` value. Something like this:

```
count_total=count_total+$_POST['received'] 
new_messages=new_messages+$_POST['received']
```

I modified the trigger:

```
... new_messages=new_messages+NEW.received ...
... inbox_count_total=inbox_count_total+NEW.received ...
```

But it does not work - the values in new_messages and inbox_count columns stay the same after update. Why?

**Question N 2**

I need `$_POST['subject']` value only in `messages_folders` table. I insert it also in `instant_messages_a` table just because the trigger needs to update `messages_folders` table with this value. Is there any way how to update `messages_folders table`

```
...subject=NEW.subject...
```

without inserting `$_POST['subject']` in `instant_messages_a` table.

Comment: Please make it one question at a time. Please define doesn't work and most important of all. please __format your code__

Comment: ok, sorry. Doesn't work - the values in `new_messages` column stay the same after update: `new_messages=new_messages+NEW.received`

Comment: when `received = 1 then new_messages=new_messages+NEW.new_messagesand what when received =0` ????

Comment: In question 1. You have not told that you want this against `received=1` or `received=0`

Answer (score 0):

Following query serves all what you want to achieve. No need of separate table, no need of trigger.

```
INSERT INTO messages_folders 
(
  addressee, sender, count_total, updated_time
  ,nickname, subject, ipadr, new_messages, photo
)
VALUES
(
   '1','2',1,NOW(),'sam'
   ,'some','3','mesg','img'
) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
count_total=count_total+1
,new_messages =concat(new_messages,'\n','mesg')
,updated_time=NOW();
```

The values in `''` will be provided by you in query.

However if you still need something different when `received=0` and when `received=1` (that diff is not clear yet from question), then you should prefer to use a procedure. I can guide about define and call it.

And if you do not want to use procedure and must do it with triggers then yes you have to use a separate table